# Flutter: I need to make the widgets scrollable so that whenever i'm scrolling with list view they will follow

Tags: flutter

I have 2 rows in my screen, the first row is consist of dropdown button and elevation button and the second row is where the stream builder located, I used flexible so that the stream builder is scrollable. What I want is every time I scroll the stream builder I want the first row to follow the scroll not stay in the screen.

[image: This how my screen looks like]

This is how my widget set:

```
Scaffold
  -Column
   -Row
     -Dropdown button
     -Elevated buton
   -Flexible
     -Streambuilder
       -stack
        -listview
```

Just like in facebook everytime you scroll down the "what's in your mind" controller disappers too, not floating like an app bar

Comment: check `CustomScrollView` widget

Comment: how does that work?

Comment: You might be looking for `SliverList` https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/slivers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside Listview add physics:  NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()

//
Listview(
physics:  NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
return .....;
)
//

Follow this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If you want that widget to disappear when you scroll, you need to wrap your `Column` in a `SingleChildScrollView` which you will need to wrap in a Flxible

Code:

```
Flexible(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child:  Column(
            //your normal code insode Column
```

Depending on your code, you may also need to make the `ListView` not scroll (as suggested by Rafid):

```
Listview( physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
```

Comment: it causes an error every time i'm using `flexible/expanded` before the `column`

Comment: Just remove the `Flexible`. The important one here is `SingleChildScrollView`.